# How to configure Magento API with Appgyver Composer?

Tags: android, ios, api, magento

I'm interested in creating a mobile app for android and ios that is connected to my magento store.

I am currently using appgyver composer to do this, but i'm unable to properly configure the magento API with appgyver to receive and send data to and from my magento store. Could someone tell me the process of integrating magento REST API with appgyver composer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using Postman app to look at the code Magento API generated and compared it with Appgyver API example, i realized the formatting was different. Luckily i came across a an REST API extension on Github for Magento, which extends Magento's REST API capabilities and also provided the format i needed. You cant find it [here](https://github.com/leoliew/magento-api).

I was then able to easily use the Appgyver Composer REST API configuration page to link Magento to the app i am trying to create.

Answer (score 0):

```
How to integrate magento api, It's getting 500 error but it working on postman, we request volley get request and put parameter in url and header also but it still not working....pls help me

RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(HomeProductActivity.this);
        JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://128.199.158.123/Devtest/api/rest/categories/?oauth_consumer_key=87fb627751a50a2666e9c4501a4bc85f&oauth_token=f4cb9148deb67e05a3531e05b9edf923&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1501669923&oauth_nonce=VcTJZa&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=xIrlLY0D1CGXkD49OduVqZhIVec=", "",
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        // display response
                        Log.d("Response", response.toString());
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d("Error.Response", "hfjf");
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                final Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                headers.put("Authorization", "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"87fb627751a50a2666e9c4501a4bc85f\",oauth_token=\"f4cb9148deb67e05a3531e05b9edf923\",oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\",oauth_timestamp=\"1501750716\",oauth_nonce=\"Imh2HF\",oauth_version=\"1.0\",oauth_signature=\"b%2F5UoepFy6QL7oFDBMAh9ij0yGM%3D\"");
                return headers;
            }
        };
        getRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(80000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS));
        requestQueue.add(getRequest);
        requestQueue.add(getRequest);
```